# Function in angular keeps getting executed

Tags: angularjs

I have this template in my project:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="/challenges.html" ng-controller="ChallengeCtrl">

    <main>
    <h3 class="headingregister">Start challenge reeks</h3>

    {{getUser()}}

        <form name="startChallengesForm" ng-submit="getChallenges()">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Doe de challenges!</button>
        </form>
    </main>

</script>
```

The getUser() function should display the current logged in users info.

This is the ChallengeCtrl:

```
app.controller('ChallengeCtrl', ['$scope', 'auth',
    function($scope, auth) {
        $scope.isLoggedIn = auth.isLoggedIn;
        $scope.currentUser = auth.currentUser;
        $scope.logOut = auth.logOut;

        $scope.getUser = function(){
            auth.getUser(auth.currentUser()).getValue(function(value){
                return value;
            });
        };

    }]);
```

this is auth.getUser:

```
auth.getUser = function(usr){
            return{
                getValue: function(callback){
                    $http({
                        method: 'POST',
                        url:'http://groep6api.herokuapp.com/user',
                        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
                        transformRequest: function(obj) {
                            var str = [];
                            for(var p in obj)
                                str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
                            return str.join("&");
                        },
                        data : {username: usr}
                    }).then(function (result) {
                        //return result.data;
                        callback(result.data);

                    });
                }
            }
        }
```

the problem is when I run the page, I see in developer tools that the function is being called over and over again, it should only display the users info.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function calls in templates get executed each digest cycle. Simply fetch the user once in your controller and assign the value to the scope

```
auth.getUser(auth.currentUser()).getValue(function(value){
    $scope.user = value;
});
```

and in your template, instead of `{{getUser()}}`

```
{{user}}
```