# Why am I getting this error when I try and access the $http var?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is the first time I have tried to do something, other than flow tutorials, with Angular.js.  I am starting off with the skeleton app from http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_application.asp.  I have tweeked things a bit for what I want to do, which is simply display the result of a GET method from my REST API.  So I have this in myAppCtrl.js:

```
app.controller("myAppCtrl", function($scope,$http) {
    $scope.message = "";
    $scope.hosts = "";
    $scope.left  = function() {return 100 - $scope.message.length;};
    $scope.clear = function() {$scope.message = "";};
    $scope.save  = function() {alert("Note Saved");};
    $scope.getHosts = function() {
        $http.get("http://172.17.0.5:3000/user").success(function(response) {$scope.hosts = response.records;});
    };
});
```

And I have this myApp.js file:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
```

But it is not working I get these errors in my crome javascript console:

```
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D
    at angular.js:63
    at Scope.$digest (angular.js:14281)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:14506)
    at bootstrapApply (angular.js:1448)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4185)
    at doBootstrap (angular.js:1446)
    at bootstrap (angular.js:1466)
    at angularInit (angular.js:1360)
    at angular.js:26176
    at HTMLDocument.trigger (angular.js:2744)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:11607(anonymous function) @ angular.js:8557Scope.$apply @ angular.js:14508bootstrapApply @ angular.js:1448invoke @ angular.js:4185doBootstrap @ angular.js:1446bootstrap @ angular.js:1466angularInit @ angular.js:1360(anonymous function) @ angular.js:26176trigger @ angular.js:2744eventHandler @ angular.js:3014
angular.js:63 Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D
```

Then after a while I get this error too:

```
GET http://172.17.0.5:3000/user net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT(anonymous function) @ angular.js:9827sendReq @ angular.js:9628serverRequest @ angular.js:9344processQueue @ angular.js:13189(anonymous function) @ angular.js:13205Scope.$eval @ angular.js:14401Scope.$digest @ angular.js:14217Scope.$apply @ angular.js:14506bootstrapApply @ angular.js:1448invoke @ angular.js:4185doBootstrap @ angular.js:1446bootstrap @ angular.js:1466angularInit @ angular.js:1360(anonymous function) @ angular.js:26176trigger @ angular.js:2744eventHandler @ angular.js:3014
angular.js:11607 Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D
    at angular.js:63
    at Scope.$digest (angular.js:14281)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:14506)
    at done (angular.js:9659)
    at completeRequest (angular.js:9849)
    at XMLHttpRequest.requestError (angular.js:9800)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:11607(anonymous function) @ angular.js:8557Scope.$apply @ angular.js:14508done @ angular.js:9659completeRequest @ angular.js:9849requestError @ angular.js:9800
```

UPDATE: This is my view ... I think:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.js"></script>
<!-- switch back to angular.min.js after debigging -->
<body>

<div ng-controller="myAppCtrl">

<h2>My Note</h2>

<p><textarea ng-model="message" cols="40" rows="10"></textarea></p>

<p>
<button ng-click="save()">Save</button>
<button ng-click="clear()">Clear</button>
</p>

<p>Number of characters left: <span ng-bind="left()"></span></p>
<p>hosts: <span ng-bind="getHosts()"></span></p>
</div>

<script src="myApp.js"></script>
<script src="myAppCtrl.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does your view look like? Are you changing models during the render phase?

Comment: Why not just use `$.get()` ?

Comment: `http://172.17.0.5:3000/user` is it in working state ? show your html code too

Comment: Yes I can curl http://172.17.0.5:3000/user from the web server.

Comment: can you show us what are you doing in your html code. we can't track from just js code

Comment: Why is the Angular `<script>` between `<html>` and `<body>`? It should be within either `<body>` or `<head>` (which you seem to be missing)

Comment: Also, I wouldn't bind to a function in your template. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33380828/function-in-angular-keeps-getting-executed/33380887#33380887

Comment: @Phil I don't know. Probably because I don't know any better and trusted the html I got from http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_application.asp would be OK.

Comment: issue is with your ng-bind line, specifically with the new line you added

Comment: Never trust anything from W3Schools. Angular provides **much** better tutorials for their own product than anyone else would. *Edit*: Oh my God, it really is like that. Find yourself a new tutorial right away!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say the problem is that `getHosts()` executes each digest cycle. When the HTTP request resolves, it triggers another digest cycle thus causing an infinite loop.

Try this instead in your controller

```
$scope.message = "";
$scope.hosts = "";
// etc, no need for a getHosts function

$http.get("http://172.17.0.5:3000/user").then(function(response) {
    $scope.hosts = response.data.records;
});
```

and in your template

```
<p>hosts: <span ng-bind="hosts"></span></p>
```

Comment: That took care of some my issue.  I still get the ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT when I try to contact http://172.17.0.5:3000/user but I guess that my not be accessible from my browser.  I suspect that http://172.17.0.5:3000/user is only access from the web server.  I probably have to set up some sort of proxy.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are changing the model within your `getHosts()` function which is binded to the view.

When you first load the page, `getHosts()` is called which then makes a call to your API and updates `$scope.hosts` with the result. Because $scope.hosts is updated, it triggers a new render which makes another API call, resulting in a loop (hence the '10 $digest() iterations reached' error).

It doesn't look like you are using `$scope.hosts` in your view.

So first replace `ng-bind="getHosts()"` with `ng-bind="hosts"`, then in your controller add the following:

```
$http.get("http://172.17.0.5:3000/user").success(function(response) {
     $scope.hosts = response.records;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here

```
<p>Number of characters left: <span ng-bind="left()"></span></p>
<p>hosts: <span ng-bind="getHosts()"></span></p>
```

the ng-bind="expression" is equal to {{expression}}, and you can NOT put the expression equal to a function.

I recommend to add ng-change [read about it here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/textarea) in textarea tag and put it equal to a function that calculate the left, and also getHost like the following:

```
<textarea ng-model="message"  ng-change="refresh()" cols="40" rows="10"></textarea>
<p>Number of characters left: {{left}}</p>
<p>hosts: {{hosts}}</p>
```

and in controller:

```
$scope.refresh  = function() {
   $scope.left =  100 - $scope.message.length;
   $http.get("http://172.17.0.5:3000/user").success(function(response) {$scope.hosts = response.records;});
};
```